# Android Gson getch data and save into listview

Tags: android, android-listview, gson

I have this simple code to fetch data with GSON and save into the listview:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<behzad> beh) {
    mcountryx = tours;
    if (mcountryTours != null) {
        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] items = { "Milk", "Butter", "Yogurt", "Toothpaste", "Ice Cream" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This code leads to an error, MessageBox:

```
Can not resolve Constructor ArrayAdaptor...
```

Whereas using the following code:

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
String[] items = { "Milk", "Butter", "Yogurt", "Toothpaste", "Ice Cream" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

into the `onCreateMethod`, that messageBox not show!
Can you please explain me what happens? thanks for attention to my problem.

My behzad Class is:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class behzad {

    @SerializedName("tourcountryname")
    public String CountryNamme;
    public TourCountry() {

    }

}
```

Comment: where is your JSON for using GSON on it.?

Comment: hi @AmrutBidri thanks you for read this post,but i think ArrayAdaptor not Construct into onPostExecute.into my code not problem to fetch GSON or json,my error into OnPostExecute Block.

Comment: if u post the behzad class it will be easy to explain

Comment: Try to change **this** by  **YourActivityName.this** (when you create the adapter)

Comment: @Rami thanks my friend,with your help solve my problem.

Comment: @AmrutBidri Thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem,with Rami help i solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future users,

You need to pass a **context** to your Adapter constructor.

`this` in your `onCreate()` referes to the Activity, while `this` inside the `onPostExecute()` refers to the `AsyncTask`(it's not a context), this is why you have `Can not resolve Constructor ArrayAdaptor...`

Change this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
```

to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AcivityName.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);
```